# At an Crud (update...) events record the change in values (who,when, old value, new value...)

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers, audit-logging

I want a system identical to Audit Logging Plugin (http://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging) but for Java.

Hibernate envers allows to store all the data for each release. It does not know what data is changed. 
I would only store the changed values. Store all values is useless in my case.

here is what I will wish:
A table with :

date_event, class_name, old_value, new_value, actor, persited_object_id
2014-12-18; person; tony; John; admin; 5

To summarize, I would like to answer the question: who ? changed what ? when ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

In Hibernate 3.x

You have a option called Listeners. That you can configure Post-Commit. You can receive add,modified and deleted events. In added events you can receive added object , In Updated Event you can receive updated prop names , old & new values. In Deleted Event you can receive deleted objects.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [HibernateInterceptor](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html), [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/) is an example how to implement one. For your requirement, the interesting method is `onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types)`. This is called when an entity is updated, you have `previousState` and `currentState` which you would compare to see if it is changed. It may get a little complicated for non trivial fields, many-to-many mappings, etc., but it is all manageable.